# how do use while loop to modify colums values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

i'm using a while loop to modify a date column with code below :

```
beg_date    end_date    t_date
2015-11-16  2015-12-20  NaN
2015-11-16  2015-12-20  NaN
```

```py
first = df.agg({"end_date": "min"}).collect()[0]['min(end_date)']

df.loc[df['end_date'] == first, 't_date']   = df['beg_date']

while df['t_date']  <= df['end_date'] : 

      df['t_date'] += 1
```

first of t_date is fist(beg_date),

Any help ?

Best ,

Comment: Just a tip, try to avoid while for iterations, use FOR. Also post the data estructure

Comment: This looks like `pandas`, also your logic is unclear. You currently have a column of `NaN`, adding `1` to `NaN` gives `NaN`. What are you really trying to achieve here? Also adding `1` means what exactly, adding 1 day?

Comment: Hi Edchum, t_date column is a date and first t_date value is a date and it's first date of beg-date

Comment: Do you want all the values in `t_date` to be the same? What do you want to do inside that while loop? If you absolutely need the loop, my suggestion would be to keep `t_date` as a variable outside of your dataframe. But if you explain your end goals, there might be a way to do what you want in pandas without loops at all which are notoriously inefficient when using pandas.

Comment: Hi Dan, i want to  replace t_date NaN with beg_date (frist one +1) using while loop or other solution,

Comment: Hi @Dan i'm trying to convert this SAS code to pandas :                                                  ``` code  if first.end_date  then t_date=beg_date;
 do while(t_date<=end_date_key);
  output;
  t_date+1;
 end;                                                                                                            
  ```

Comment: @abakar you will need to *edit* your question to provide some simplified sample inputs and your desired output. As it stands, your question is incomprehensible I'm afraid.